# Заполнение textarea полей из дочернего окна - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте друзья, есть окно (родительское) и в этом окне есть 3 текстовых поля

```
<textarea name="jaloby" rows="5" class="form-control" id="jaloby" ></textarea> 
<textarea name="obekt" rows="5" class="form-control" id="obekt" ></textarea> 
<textarea name="diagnoz" rows="5" class="form-control" id="diagnoz" ></textarea>
```

С помощью JS открывается дочернее окно и там тоже есть три текстовых поля

```
<textarea name="jaloby2" rows="5" class="form-control" id="jaloby2" ></textarea> 
<textarea name="obekt2" rows="5" class="form-control" id="obekt2" ></textarea> 
<textarea name="diagnoz2" rows="5" class="form-control" id="diagnoz2" ></textarea>
```

Как сделать чтоб при нажатии например на кнопку значения текстовых полей дочернего окна передались в текстовые поля

в родителстком окне.

Кстати дочернее окно открывается через след. код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function go(addr) {
  window.open(addr,"MyWin", "menubar=no,width=1200,height=970");
  }
```

И ссылка такая

```
<a href = ''  "  onclick="go('vendors/tree/demo/index.php?id=<?php echo $id ; ?>&fio=<?php 

echo $fio ; ?>'); return false;">
```

Буду благодарен за ответы !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код для дочернего окна.

HTML

```
<textarea name="jaloby2" rows="5" class="form-control" id="jaloby2" ></textarea>
```

JS

```
let jaloby, jaloby2, doc;
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    jaloby2 = document.querySelector('#jaloby2');
    doc = window.opener.document;
    jaloby = doc.querySelector('#jaloby');

    jaloby2.addEventListener('change', () => {
        jaloby.value = jaloby2.value
    }
});
```

`window.opener` позволяет получить доступ к `window` родительского окна. А уже через него можно получить доступ к `document` и делать с DOM все, что захочется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Алексей ! У меня возник ещё один вопрос исходя из своей неопытности в области JS. Выше привели код только для одного поля правильно ? а для остальных полей тоже написать отдельно ?

Comment: @AlexStassov Да. Разберись в коде по строчкам, чтобы не накосячить.